# Google Play Game Services weirdness on failed login/retry (Activity Lifecycle)

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard, activity-lifecycle

**Problem**

User presses 'Scores' button (which kicks off the Login process to log into the Google Play Games Services via **beginUserInitiatedSignIn()**), and then presses the 'home' key before it manages to log in.  When returning to the app, it looks like the play services tries to 'pick up where it left off' and continues to sign in.  But it's not quite right.

**onActivityResult** returns 0 at first (Not successful, which I would expect as it was interupted), then attempts to log in again and returns -1 which means **Successful** Great! But no, if I call getGameHelper().isSignedIn(); it returns **false**.

What is happening here?!  Anything I may be overlooking or anything I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you get a call to [ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected%28android.os.Bundle%29) (or `onSignInSucceeded` if you are using `GameHelper`), you are not connected.

Your `onActivityResult` should call [GoogleApiClient.connect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect%28%29) when it receives a successful response so that the appropriate connection can be established and your `onConnected` callback is made.

Comment: Excellent!  Got, it, thanks @ianhanniballake.  I think I understand now.  The result from onActivityResult only means that the login activity has finished successfully - not that the user has logged in successfuly?  It does though beg the question, if it aborts, then attempts to sign in again, why doesn't it sign in successfuly if it's left alone to try?!  I'll ask another question for that though as you've answered this one - cheers :-)

Comment: Basically, the `startResolutionForResult`/`onActivityResult` dance is just to get user permission so that Google Play Services can generate an auth token for the user. `connect()` is what then checks with Google Play Services to retrieve a valid auth token, hence why you need an additional `connect()` call to retrieve the token after `onActivityResult`.

That's also why on subsequent logins, a single call to `connect()` is enough - there's already an auth token so no need to do anything else.

Comment: Thank for this @ianhanniballake, I'm beginning to udererstand it a bit more although still a little confused.  Could u please take a look at my other question which covers this?  Thanks :-)